# How to make buttons change colors when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, colors

I set up 3 buttons and am wondering how to make them change colors when clicked on.
'Yes' should be green
'No' should be red
'Maybe' should be red also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Trivia!</title>

  <script></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
    <hr>

    <h3>Do you love me?
      <h3>

        <button id="q1button">Yes</button>
        <button id="q2button">No</button>
        <button id="q3button">Maybe</button>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? They are two completely different languages.

Comment: I meant Javascript

Comment: FYI, your `<h3>` tag is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```css
button:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#q1button:focus {
    background-color: green;
    color: pink;
}
#q2button:focus {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
#q3button:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
                <hr>

                <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
                    
                <button id="q1button">Yes</button>
                <button id="q2button">No</button>
                <button id="q3button">Maybe</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Note that OP wants different colors for different buttons

Comment: Maybe is supposed to be red according to OP

Comment: The problem with using focus, is that is they click on something else the focus, and the color, go away.

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: Thank you.This is actually what I am looking for @SatoTakeru

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using javascript. I think something like this works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
            <hr>

            <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
                
            <button id="q1button" onclick="this.style.background = 'green'">Yes</button>
            <button id="q2button" onclick="this.style.background = 'red'">No</button>
            <button id="q3button" onclick="this.style.background = 'red'">Maybe</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Work around for all of them getting highlighted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
            <button id="q1button" onclick="changeBg(this);">Yes</button>
            <button id="q2button" onclick="changeBg(this);">No</button>
            <button id="q3button" onclick="changeBg(this);">Maybe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function changeBg(button){
            if(button.id == "q1button"){
                button.style.background = "green";
                document.getElementById("q2button").style.background = "transparent";
                document.getElementById("q3button").style.background = "transparent";
            }
            else if(button.id == "q2button"){
                button.style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById("q1button").style.background = "transparent";
                document.getElementById("q3button").style.background = "transparent";
            }
            if(button.id == "q3button"){
                button.style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById("q1button").style.background = "transparent";
                document.getElementById("q2button").style.background = "transparent";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem here is that if you click more than one, they all get highlighted.

Comment: How do I get around all of them being highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
<style>
 .yes:focus {
  background-color: green;
 }
.no:focus {
 background-color: red;
}
.maybe:focus {
 background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<button class="yes">Yes</button>
<button class="no">No</button>
<button class="maybe">Maybe</button>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: The problem with using focus, is that is they click on something else the focus, and the color, go away.

Comment: @bobsfriend True

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to add a class name stored in a data attribute. That makes it easy for you to decide the color's button directly in the HTML markup.

Notice that removing the color class restores the button exactly as it was before.

```js
$(".answer").on("click", function(){
  
  // Reset other answers.
  $(".answer").removeClass("red green")

  // Use the classname stored in the button's data attribute
  $(this).addClass($(this).data("color"))
})
```

```css
.green{
  background: green;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
    <hr>

    <h3>Do you love me?</h3>

        <button class="answer" id="q1button" data-color="green">Yes</button>
        <button class="answer" id="q2button" data-color="red">No</button>
        <button class="answer" id="q3button" data-color="red">Maybe</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

The same in plain JS is:

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")

btns.forEach(function(btn){

  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Reset other answers.
    btns.forEach(function(btn){
      btn.classList.remove("red")
      btn.classList.remove("green")
    })
    
    // Use the classname stored in the button's data attribute
    this.classList.add(this.getAttribute("data-color"))
  })
})
```

```css
.green{
  background: green;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
    <hr>

    <h3>Do you love me?</h3>

        <button class="answer" id="q1button" data-color="green">Yes</button>
        <button class="answer" id="q2button" data-color="red">No</button>
        <button class="answer" id="q3button" data-color="red">Maybe</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the color even if the button is not focused you need to use JS to maintain the button state. You may add a `click` event listener on a common parent and if the target of that event is a button just toggle an `active` class on it.

When a button is clicked it could be reasonable to unselect the previous choice (if any) in the *same* section, but in case concurrent selections are allowed then remove the inner `if` block.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {

  let currentTgt       = ev.target;
  let previousSelected, 
      section;
  
  /* a button is clicked? */
  if (currentTgt.matches('button')) {

    /* comment the next 'if' block if multiple buttons 
     * selection is allowed at the same time. 
     *
     * Is a button already active and that button is not
     * the same button I've just clicked? Then remove the
     * active class from that button
     */
    section = currentTgt.closest('.section');
    previousSelected = section.querySelector('.active');
    if (previousSelected && currentTgt !== previousSelected) {
       previousSelected.classList.remove('active');
    }

    currentTgt.classList.toggle('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.q1button.active { color: green }

.q2button.active,
.q3button.active { color: red }
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h2>Question #1</h2>
  <button class="q1button">Yes</button>
  <button class="q2button">No</button>
  <button class="q3button">Maybe</button>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <h2>Question #2</h2>
  <button class="q1button">Yes</button>
  <button class="q2button">No</button>
  <button class="q3button">Maybe</button>
</div>
```

As a side note I suggest to use classes instead of id for the buttons if you plan to have more than one section with multiple questions (and buttons)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with just CSS and some changes to the HTML.

In the example I use labels shaped like buttons to trigger inputs which will control the visual aesthetic of the buttons. This is handled in the CSS with the `:checked` and adjacent `+` selectors to modify the colors of the `label` `.button`.

```css
.inputController {
  display: none;
}
.inputController:checked + .button-greenCK {
  background-color: green;
}
.inputController:checked + .button-redCK {
  background-color: red;
} 

.button {
  font-size: 0.65em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.button_label {}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Trivia!</title>

        <script>

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Single Choice</h2>
                <hr>

                <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
                
                <input id="q1button" name="trivia1" class="inputController" type="radio"/>
                <label class="button button-greenCK" for="q1button">
                  <span class="button_value">Yes</span>
                </label>
                
                <input id="q2button" name="trivia1" class="inputController" type="radio"/>
                <label class="button button-redCK" for="q2button">
                  <span class="button_value">No</span>
                </label>
                
                <input id="q3button" name="trivia1" class="inputController" type="radio"/>
                <label class="button button-redCK" for="q3button">
                  <span class="button_label">Maybe</span>
                </label>

            </div>

        </div>
        
        <div class="container">

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 2: Multiple Choice</h2>
                <hr>

                <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
                
                <input id="q4button" name="trivia2" class="inputController" type="checkbox"/>
                <label class="button button-greenCK" for="q4button">
                  <span class="button_value">Yes</span>
                </label>
                
                <input id="q5button" name="trivia2" class="inputController" type="checkbox"/>
                <label class="button button-redCK" for="q5button">
                  <span class="button_value">No</span>
                </label>
                
                <input id="q6button" name="trivia2" class="inputController" type="checkbox"/>
                <label class="button button-redCK" for="q6button">
                  <span class="button_label">Maybe</span>
                </label>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aside of the significant markup change, another issue with this approach is that you need a reset button or a javascript snippet in case you want to just unselect a choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript event listener, and change the color like that when it is clicked on.

You also have to unset the other buttons when a different one is pushed.

```js
const btn1= $('#q1button');
const btn2= $('#q2button');
const btn3= $('#q3button');

btn1.click( function() {
    btn1.css('background', 'green');
    btn2.css('background', 'initial');
    btn3.css('background', 'initial');
});

btn2.click( function() {
    btn1.css('background', 'initial');
    btn2.css('background', 'red');
    btn3.css('background', 'initial');
});

btn3.click( function() {
    btn1.css('background', 'initial');
    btn2.css('background', 'initial');
    btn3.css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice</h2>
            <hr>

            <h3>Do you love me?<h3>
                
            <button id="q1button">Yes</button>
            <button id="q2button">No</button>
            <button id="q3button">Maybe</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```